# center image horizontally and repeating vertically

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to show an image centered horizontally, with repeating it vertically to cover the height of the screen.

I tried with this:

```
Center(
    child: Image.asset('test.png', repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY),
)
```

But what I get is an image centered horizontally and vertically without the repeat.

Comment: What do you mean my repeating ?

Comment: repeating y to cover the height of the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your Container has the full height you want. To fill the whole screen you can do this:

```
Container(
  height: double.infinity,
  child: Image.asset('test.png',
    repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  ),
);
```

Comment: this code repeats the image, but it does not start from the top of the screen

Comment: @GiacomoM because it uses the default center `alignment`

Comment: @pskink how can i change that?

Comment: @GiacomoM change [Image.alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/alignment.html) property

Comment: @pskink If I use the alignment property I lose the repeating of the image

Comment: I've updated response with the correct form of aligning the image without losing the repetition. If this answer fixes your issue, don't forget to mark it as correct.